# Javascript architecture of my CMS application

Tags: javascript, jquery, architecture, backbone.js, publish-subscribe

I'm building a CMS in which will have some features using Javascript/Ajax as paging, searches (both using ajax) and some features like image crop and others (without ajax).

My app is not a Single Page Application, I'm looking for a architectural solution of my Javascripts which involves the separation of concerns for the future maintenance.

I was taking at look at MVC solutions like Backbone.js, Spine.js, Dojo Toolkit and Pub/Sub Pattern, but I don't know if these solutions is the way to go in my app, however, may be solutions with large amounts of resources that I do not need.

Someone can help me and indicate me a simple and not much complex solution (a EXAMPLE with code is much better) which focus in separation of concerns?

(Like I was saying I'll use simple Javascript features like paging and searches with ajax and some features like image crop, forms validation, ajax grids and jquery plugins in general)

I know jQuery is great for DOM manipulation, however, only jQuery don't serve a good architectural solution, What I might be combining with jQuery for a good architecture/separation?

Comment: I mostly use Backbone to get a nice MVC like architecture.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for a reference architecture for large scale javascript development, have a look at BoilerplateJS. It is not a library, but startup codebase with samples for complex product development. As you asked, it shows best practices of

- solution structure
- product modularization
- self contained UI components

And many more architectural concerns. I wrote it to share my experience which I gained doing couple of complex JS products.

http://boilerplatejs.org

Answer (score 0):

If you are creating an one page application something like Knockout.js is great. If you are making a website with app like features a framework that uses jQuery is mostly better. In that case go for something like Backbone.js (there are others)

You should try a few different frameworks and see which one you like best for you website/application. I know this isn't a great answer but different applications have different needs.